# Show content with fancybox like a Javascript Alert

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I try to show the content from a PHP-file in a fancybox but I can't handle it.

Now it's the following situation:
If a file permission problem occures a `<div id="error">` is shown on the website. I'd like to have the content from `<div id="error">` in fancybox. Everything I try I get the notice "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."

That means the fancybox, it the file permission error occures, should be shown when the page is loading and not like usual shown when some events like click or mouseover.

For example, if the error exists, the following content should be shown in the fancybox:

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; background:#f00;">
  <p>Failure</p>
</div>
```

This snippet is located in a file `security_check.php`. Now there are two possibilities. The 1st is to load the `security_check.php` directly into the fancybox or to put in the mentioned above snippet.

So: how to load file contents into the fancybox?

Comment: No, your description is not clear enough. Post code you have so far and exact errors you're getting.

Comment: For example, if the error exists, the following content should be shown in the fancybox:<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#f00;"><p>Failure</p></div> ... this snippet is located in a file security_check.php. Now there are two possibilities. The 1st is to load the security_check.php directly into the fancybox or to put in the mentioned above snippet. Is it explained better now?

Comment: so you ask how to load file contents into the fancybox?

Comment: @shadow yes, that's the point

Comment: next time please use the edit link rather than post code in comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have such code to load the file contents into the DIV holding the fancybox contents:

```
$(function() {
    $("#MyFancyContents").load("security_check.php");
});
```

The fancybox link should then be something like:

```
<a id="MyFancyLink" href="#MyFancyContents">Show</a>
```

And to activate, what you probably already have:

```
$("#MyFancyLink").fancybox();
```

Edit: in order to activate the fancy box when page loads rather than just by clicking the link, have such line instead:

```
$("#MyFancyLink").fancybox().trigger('click');
```

Comment: This is what I've already tried but then the fancybox will be shown by a click. I don't wanto to activate it by click: I'd like to have it automatically on pageload.

Comment: @shadow Now i Used this: $(function() {
    $("#error").load("includes/modules/security_check.php");
});

$("#test").fancybox().trigger('click'); an nothing happend only a failure "Direct access is not allowed". Do you have an email or messenger? Then I could show you the files

Comment: @Ron you need to have it in the same function like this: `$(function() { $("#error").load("includes/modules/security_check.php"); $("#test").fancybox().trigger('click'); });` helping in email or messenger is not relevant, the whole point of this site is that others can help as well and get help from everyone. For "one on one" help you can try the Chat when you have enough reputation score - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @shadow Unfortunately I need some more reputation points to use the caht

Comment: @Ron yes you need 20 (12 more) post some answers and you'll have this really fast. Did you try my last suggestion?

Comment: @shadow Sorry, but I didn't see it. But now it works. Your last hint is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Have I missed something? To simulate a JS alert simply:

```
        $.fancybox({ title: "Registration Complete", autoCenter: true, content: "<div id='alert1' ><p>Well done, you have registered!</p></div>" });
```

Too easy, right?

Comment: Current version should be $.fancybox.open