# Replace a JavaScript alert pop up with a fancy box alert

Tags: javascript, forms, fancybox, alert

I'm looking to replace the generic JavaScript alert pop-up box with a fancy box... 
Here is the code that I currently have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            /*
            *   Examples - various
            */

            $("#various1").fancybox({
                'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none'
            });

        });
    </script>
```

**Below is the JavaScript used for the alert...**

```
    <script language="Javascript1.2">
<!--
var message = "Print this Page";

function printpage() {
window.print();  
}
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["zipform"]["Zip"].value;
if (x>97999)
  {
  alert("#inline1");
  return false;
  }
}
//-->
</script>
```

**Below is the form section I'm using...**

```
<form name="zipform" onsubmit="return validateForm()" language="JavaScript" method="POST" action="#">
              Enter Your Zip Code <input type="text" name="Zip" size="5" maxlength="5">
              <input type="submit" value="Start">
            </form>
```

**Below is the div I'd like to display on the site...**

```
<div id="content">
  <p><a id="various1" href="#inline1" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">Inline</a></p>
    <div style="display: none;">
        <div id="inline1" style="width:400px;height:100px;overflow:auto; ">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis mi eu elit tempor facilisis id et neque.</div></div></div>
```

I've found this link [Show content with fancybox like a Javascript Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642344/show-content-with-fancybox-like-a-javascript-alert) but it really doesn't answer the question I have. I **do not** want a clickable link; I want the div fancybox to pop up when there is a JavaScript alert.

Comment: `$("#inline1").fancybox().trigger('click');`

Comment: You cannot make something work exactly like the real `alert()` box because you can't force the browser to "freeze" the window the way real `alert()` and `confirm()` do.

Comment: @Pointy can the alert() call a div to be displayed? as something like alert("#inline1"); the #inline1 would display the error message at a specific section on the site.

Comment: @pixelpusher not in any browser I'm aware of, unfortunately.

Comment: @mgraph I tried that and it didn't work... here is another link that is similar to what i'm looking for but I don't understand the code to it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431155/change-js-alert-to-dom-error-message-div

Comment: here is the other link i mentioned before that almost does exatly what I want however I don't know how to incorporate it into my code shown above... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642344/show-content-with-fancybox-like-a-javascript-alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the window attached to the alert can't be modified since is a system object, and therefore CSS can't do anything there.

So my best bet would be that you would create an HTML element that would mock the alert window, and style it however you want... I, for example, usually go for this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: yes those styles of windows i'd like to have however i'd need the code for them to make them work as an alert/error when used with my form...

Comment: yes but how could I call the dialog when there is an error? could you provide some code/example of implementation to the code I provided up above? that's where i'm stuck...

Comment: Your question was different. Try it and edit your question, and we will see where you are stucked...

Comment: ultimate goal is... **I need to show an error message in a div on the page.**

Comment: thanks for your help everyone... i figured it out with the help of info provided.

Answer (score 1):

There is manual usage for that - `$.fancybox("#inline1");`